# Run a VPN client on a remote web site react

Tags: reactjs, client, vpn, openvpn

I am working on react app SPA and I need to fetch data from remote API. The problem is, it requires VPN connection to use it. Currently I am using FortiClient app for windows, logging through my credentials and everything is working locally. How do I set it up for remote website though?

I've been reading about [node-openvpn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-openvpn) package but it doesn't seem to work with it's example usage from docs.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.